# Why does a wound itch while it's healing?

Tags: healing

During healing of wound (almost in final stage) it begins to itch a lot around wound.

I wondering what the reason for this is?

Answer (score 2):

While healing your wound the cells in and around it are enhancing their communication via messenger substances to quicken and coordinate the healing process. These messengers irritate the sore nerves which we feel as itching.

Skin tension is another factor to itching.

Scratching is bad for the healing process in any way.

Comment: Interesting answer. Could you provide a reference?

Comment: @GoodGravy i don't remember the exact source but [this](http://www.advancedtissue.com/understanding-wound-healing-itching-dilemma/) i found on a quick search.